# Is possible to send data from a minifilter kernel driver to a Python Application?

Tags: python, driver, antivirus, minifilter

I'm building a Minifilter Kernel Driver for Antivirus purposes that whanever a filesystem operation (open | write | read) happens it retrieves the filename and process ID involved in the operation. I was wondering myself if it's possible to make the Driver send the data (file name and PID) to a user-mode Python application, for example using FltSendMessage ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is possible, however, it won't be without any hack. First of all, there aren't any libraries/wrappers to interact with a minifilter driver other than the one in C++ provided by Microsoft. Based on that, you could:

- Have a C++ program that intercepts data from the kernel driver and pipe its output from a Python program
  or
- Have C++/Python binding (calling a C++ function from Python) for example using Pybind11/SWIG etc...